# Selector for HIDDEN fields by PARTIAL name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, hidden

I have a set of hidden fields that have similar names just appended with an index counter.
Then I have a function that needs to loop through all those hidden fields and alert the value.

If it's a regular text field, I can easily do it like this and it's working fine:

```
        <c:forEach items="${ctsDictionary}" var="cts" varStatus="status">
            <c:set var="summCtr" value="${summCtr + 1}" scope="page"/>
            <input type="text" id="currClock<c:out value='${summCtr}'/>" name="currClock<c:out value='${summCtr}'/>" value="<c:out value='${cts.value.clock_no}'/>" />              
        </c:forEach>        


        $('input[name*="currClock"]').each(function() {
              alert($(this).val());
        });
```

But the moment I convert it to a hidden field and select them as shown below, it's not working.  It's not looping.  Any ideas?

```
        <c:forEach items="${ctsDictionary}" var="cts" varStatus="status">
            <c:set var="summCtr" value="${summCtr + 1}" scope="page"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="currClock<c:out value='${summCtr}'/>" name="currClock<c:out value='${summCtr}'/>" value="<c:out value='${cts.value.clock_no}'/>" />                
        </c:forEach>        


        $('input:hidden[name*="currClock"]').each(function() {
              alert($(this).val());
        });
```

UPDATE: As Yuriy has pointed out, it's working in jsfiddle.  But for the life of me, I couldn't figure out why it's not working in my JSP.  I even hard coded the hidden field exactly the same as in the jsfiddle and it's still not selecting.  I'm posting my whole JSP in the hopes that someone with good eyes can spot what's wrong.  The jQuery selection happens inside the getCrewDetails() function.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<DIV id="approveCrewSummListDiv" class="normalFont" style="height:360px;">

<table id="approveCrewSummTable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header" style="color:#FFFFFF;">
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Clock No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>First Clock In</th>
            <th>Last Clock Out</th>
            <th>Total Approved</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <c:set var="summCtr" value="0" scope="page" />

        <c:forEach items="${ctsDictionary}" var="cts" varStatus="status">

            <c:set var="summCtr" value="${summCtr + 1}" scope="page"/>

            <input type="hidden" id="prevClock<c:out value='${summCtr}'/>" name="prevClock<c:out value='${summCtr}'/>" value="<c:out value='${ctsDictionary[status.index-1].clock_no}'/>" />
            <input type="hidden" id="currClock<c:out value='${summCtr}'/>" name="currClock<c:out value='${summCtr}'/>" value="<c:out value='${cts.value.clock_no}'/>" />
            <input type="hidden" id="nextClock<c:out value='${summCtr}'/>" name="nextClock<c:out value='${summCtr}'/>" value="<c:out value='${ctsDictionary[status.index+1].clock_no}'/>" />                

            <tr id="<c:out value='${cts.value.clock_no}'/>" onclick="getCrewDetails(this.id); return false;"  >
                <td align="center"><c:out value='${cts.value.approval}'/></td>
                <td align="center"><c:out value='${cts.value.clock_no}'/></td>
                <td align="center"><c:out value='${cts.value.employeeName}'/></td>
                <td align="center"><c:out value='${cts.value.mod_start_date_timStr}'/></td>
                <td align="center"><c:out value='${cts.value.mod_end_date_timeStr}'/></td>
                <td align="center"><c:out value='${cts.value.mod_elap_timeStr}'/></td>
            </tr>   

        </c:forEach>        

    </tbody>
</table>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {    

        //Datatable transform
        $('#approveCrewSummTable').dataTable( {        
            "paging":   true,   //enables paging functionality
            "autoWidth": false, //stops DataTable glitch that sets table width that exceeds DIV container
            "deferRender": true, //defers rendering for performance enhancement or so the API says
            "displayLength": 8, //set the number of records displayed per page
            "lengthChange": false, //do not show option for changing no. of entries displayed
            "order": [[ 2, "asc" ]] //default initial sort by name ASC  
            //"ordering": true,        
            //"info":     true
        });

        //Pop-up dialog window that will contain the seleted crew's details         
        $( "#approveCrewDetDiv" ).dialog({
              //title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
              closeOnEscape: true,
              draggable: false,
              //position: 'center',
              width: 975,
              height: 610, //'auto',
              modal: true,
              resizable: false,
              autoOpen: false,
              open: function (event, ui) {
                //$('#approveCrewDetDiv').css('overflow', 'hidden'); //hide scroll bars
              }
              //close: function () { $(this).remove() }
        });     
    });

    function getCrewDetails(clockNo){
        //alert("Getting crew details for clockNo: " + clockNo);

        //Get previous and next clock nos with reference to selected clock no           
        var ctr = 1;
        var prevClockNo = 0;
        var nextClockNo = 0;
        $('input:hidden[name*="currClock"]').each(function() {
           alert("VAL:"+$(this).val());  //THIS IS NOT ALERTING, SO IT'S NOT LOOPING
           if (($(this).val()) == clockNo){
                prevClockNo = $('#prevClock'+ctr).val();
                nextClockNo = $('#nextClock'+ctr).val();
           }
           ctr++;
        });

        //Open crew details pop-up
        $( "#approveCrewDetDiv" ).dialog("open");

        //Get data for crew details pop-up
        $.get(  "ApprovalController",
                { 
                    faction: 'getCrewDetails',
                    pltNo: $('#pltNoHid').val(),
                    acPayDate: $( "#acPayDate" ).val(),
                    shift: $('#acShiftDD').val(),
                    clockNo: clockNo,
                    prevClockNo: prevClockNo,
                    nextClockNo: nextClockNo,
                    beforeSend: function() {  //Show AJAX wait icon
                        //$('#approveCrewDetWrapperDiv').show();  //Make target wrapper DIV visible
                        $('#approveCrewDetDiv').load('AJAXLoading.jsp'); //Load the AJAX wait page to the target DIV
                    }                       
                },
                function(data,status){
                    //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                    //$.each(data, function(i, item){
                    //  alert("Data: " + item.field + "=" + item.value);
                        //$("#"+item.field).val(item.value);
                    //});

                    //Populate crew details div
                    //$('#approveCrewDetDiv').replaceWith(data);  //this DIV is inside "dialog-modal" DIV inside ApproveCrew2.jsp
                    $('#approveCrewDetDiv').html(data);  //this DIV is inside "dialog-modal" DIV inside ApproveCrew2.jsp

                }
                //"json"
        );  
    }   

</script>

</DIV>
```

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML? Also, why do you have `{` after your alert?

Comment: What happens if you keep the input type as hidden, but remove the `:hidden` from the Jquery?

Comment: Is the extra `{` a copying error or is it in your real code? That syntax error will keep your code from running.

Comment: David: Same behavior.  Not looping.

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/rnc0qe03/

Comment: Barmar: Just a copying error.  Edited my post.  Thanks for pointing  it out.

Comment: Yuriy: I'm stumped then. I used the exact same selector and even hard coded the hidden fields like in your jsfiddle, but it's still not working.  I'll post my whole JSP in the hopes that someone can see what's wrong.  Thanks.